# VC++ MFC PowerPoint Slideshow Ignore Keyboard Events

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, powerpoint, ole, office-automation

I have an MFC VC++ application which opens a PowerPoint file directly as a slideshow. After the slideshow is running, my application would catch all the keyboard events fired and perform actions such as next slide, previous slide etc.

**Problem:**

1. If the system has Office 2010 or lower version installed everything works fine. But with Office 2013 or Office 2016 installed, my application is unable to catch keyboard interrupts because PowerPoint takes in all the interrupts. Is there any way to disable this? I want my application to get all the interrupts.
2. When the slideshow ends, PowerPoint shows a popup stating that the file is opened in read-only and that it should be saved in another location. Is there a way to disable all popups/alerts? I tried using the setting the DisplayAlerts to ppFalse by temporarily upgrading my Msppt to a later version but still did not work.

**Note:** I am using MSPPT8.olb file. I know this is a very old version but will using the latest version make things better?

Comment: Have you tried system hook with DLL?

Comment: You are asking two unrelated questions. Stackoverflow works best, when there is only one question per - well - question. Please split your question into two. Adding code should help you get better results as well.

Comment: @Jin, there is already a keyboard hook in place because of which my application was able to catch all the keyboard interrupts in earlier version of Office i.e. <= 2010. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: To avoid the save prompt at the end, it might be sufficient to set the presentation's .Saved property to True before or at the last slide.

Comment: I'm referring this, http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.jp/2009/06/how-to-create-global-system-windows.html. I built my keyboard logger with that and had never missed with any other process.

Comment: @Jin: You linked to a blog entry on writing a CBT hook. CBT hooks don't intercept keyboard input. Besides, even when setting up a [low level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx), any hook that gets installed later is enqueued to the front of the hook chain, thus potentially preventing your hook from ever seeing the input. An arms race you cannot win.